# Design Strategies for Integrating Enroll Plan-Specific Features in a Django Project

Tags: django, design-patterns, architecture

I am working on a Django project that comprises three main components:

1. **`nkb_assessment_backend`**: Handles assessments and exams, featuring apps like `nkb_exam` and `nkb_exam_extensions`.
2. **`nkb_learning_backend`**: Manages learning-related functionalities including user enroll plans, with apps such as `nkb_auth_v2`.
3. **`nkb_backend`**: Serves as an overarching layer that possibly integrates or orchestrates functionalities of the above two components.

**Requirement**: We need to introduce functionality for enroll plan-specific exam slots in the `nkb_assessment_backend`, where these slots are dependent on user enroll plans managed in the `nkb_learning_backend`. The challenge is to implement this feature without creating direct dependencies or coupling between the two backend components.

**Constraints**:

- Avoid modifications to the `nkb_assessment_backend`, particularly its database schema or existing models.
- Maintain a loosely coupled architecture.
- Ensure the solution is scalable and maintainable.

**Question**:
What are the best practices or strategies to implement this feature within the given constraints and architecture? I am looking for insights or alternative approaches that could efficiently integrate this functionality while maintaining the structural integrity of our Django project.